# I Can Be Innovation - What Am I?

Tags: word, wordplay, rhyme

> You use me, perhaps every day,
>
> while too much can lead to your dismay.
>
> I can be innovation, I can be a large blast.
>
> However, that won't last.
>
> You can see me when I am deadly,
>
> while I am invisible when you use me.

**What Am I?**

Hint:

> _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> Electricity

You use me, perhaps every day,

> That's true.  I do.

while too much can lead to your dismay.

> My electric bill already bums me out.

I can be innovation, I can be a large blast.

> ideas can be called "sparks".  Large blasts could be lightning or an arc flash.

However, that won't last.

> both are short duration

You can see me when I am deadly,

> lightning and arc flashes

while I am invisible when you use me.

> normal use, I can't see it.

Comment: This is correct! However, line 3 was referring to rot13(N fgevxr bs yvtugavat pna or dhvgr qrnqyl.)

Comment: rot13(Gunaxf!  Sbe jung vg'f jbegu, na nep synfu pna or cerggl qrnqyl gbb.)

Comment: Yes, line 4 was correct, however, rot13(Va yvar guerr V jnf ersreevat gb uvtu nzbhagf bs enj ryrpgevpvgl orvat yrguny, engure guna na ryrpgevpvgl ovyy orvat n ohzzre, rira gubhtu vg vf.)